# Bonjour - DNS_SD.jar library for linux?

Tags: java, linux, bonjour, dns-sd

I'm actually using the dns_sd.jar library in a Java program running on my MAC to register a Bonjour service.

This library is imported in the Java project using the package: com.apple.dnssd.*;
I tried several time to understand where does this library comes from ? I suppose that this library is created by Apple and already installed on each Mac OSx. Is that correct ?

It seems that that the same API of this library is available on Linux and windows. So does that means there are other dns_sd.jar for each specific OS ? Or can we just use the same library on Linux and windows ?

Why is this library not provided on the Apple developper website ? I looked everywhere !

I'm asking all these question because I want to know if I can transpose easily my Java program on a linux system ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same findings and the same question; where is the dns_sd.jar on Mountain Lion ? Is it actually gone (forever) since Oracle has taken over Java distribution ?

Bonjour SDK works perfectly on Windows, and I am able to build a service on top of it. Trying to port the same package to OSX I get unsatisfied link error, even if I manually include the Windows version of dns_sd.jar

Maybe there is some native OSX code missing ?

It is a bit funny that Bonjour works well on Windows, but not on OS X in later versions, isn´t it?

Comment: Glad to ear that I'm not the only one having this problem..

So on my system the dns_sd.jar is located at : /System/Library/Java/Extension But I'm not able to know if this library was already included in the OS.

I saw that on the developer website of Apple we can download the mDNSresponder directory that contains java source file of this library. I don't understand why they don't deliver directly the .jar file…

So know I want to know how I can transpose my code on Linux. Does anyone know the procedure for that ?

Thanks !